# Reverse Repeater Order asp.net /c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i'm working on items page where user can insert items into system and all items shown in repeater in the home page ,the latest items are displayed on the bottom of the page whilst the first items are displayed on the top ,
Is there a way to reverse the order such that the latest updates in the repeater are always displayed on top ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: change the data source

Comment: @diiN_ no,i'm trying to pick up a thread.

Comment: @Hogan thank you man that's it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Repeater.DataSource = data.Reverse();
Repeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: it's get solved i changed the select command to this SELECT * FROM [item] ORDER BY [item_id] DESC it worked like charm